# Script fails when the computer is locked (QTP 11.0) .Is there any workaround?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I use QTP 11.0.
When i run a script and in between if computer gets locked, the script fails.Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I want the script to run even when locked.Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You must unlock the computer.  QTP/UFT requires an "interactive" desktop session to do much of the automation, and the Windows OS behaves differently when it is locked.

A good way around this issue is to use Virtual Machines for your automation lab that always remain unlocked.  Access security is then maintained by the host machine or the client software used to access the VM's.

Comment: i have no idea on Virtual machines? can u plz elaborate it in detail...as what it is?

Comment: @user90 virtual machines are entire computing environments being emulated through software.  You should find a wealth of information on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a lazy way.. But actually it works.. Save the below code as vbs file and double clik on it before execution.

```
do
set w=createobject("Wscript.shell")
w.sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}"
wscript.sleep 5000
loop
```

It will simply press Numlock , until you stop the script.

Comment: so does it mean it will not allow my pc to get locked?

Comment: Yes.. It won't be locked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have a solution for this! You can use some screen saver blocker to avoid this issue.... that would make your computer unlocked until/unless you terminate the blocker process.

You can download this type of tool from google itself! I have never used that for my projects, but heard that there is some option like this. So just have a try - good luck!

Comment: Worth noting that this only prevents locks due to inactivity.  A machine can be locked in many other ways.  In an automation lab environment, one of the most common is to RDP into a machine and then it gets locked when you disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I swear by Caffeine.
Found here: http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/ your PC will never be blocked or go to sleep again!

I have also noticed that when the screensaver goes active the screenshots are all black in the Results Viewer!

Answer (score 0):

We can change the settings from control panel "**No Screen Saver** and **Computer Goes to Sleep** to **Never**". Hope this will help you on your local machine.