# Can i unlock laptop using vb script?Is there a way to do so?

Tags: qtp

I want to run my scripts in QTP at night so that the day time is saved to do some work(because when the csript runs nothing else can be dome), so i want to unlock my laptop and start execution of script automatically.Is there a way to do so?

I am using QTP 11.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Task Scheduler.  And probably a question for Super User?

Comment: Scheduling is possible through Task manager which i m aware of...but how do i unlock my laptop?

Comment: Task Scheduler has an option to run when logged out, so as long as the laptop is powered on (plugged in is preferable) and the OS is running, it will run your task.  (Laptops may be pickier about this than desktops, but they should still work.)

Comment: But the QTP behaves differently when running on a locked system.So was looking for an option to trigger some action to unlock the system

Comment: You already asked essentially the same question.  Please don't double-post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698947/script-fails-when-the-computer-is-locked-qtp-11-0-is-there-any-workaround/24700157#24700157

Comment: FYI it is not the same question.In that i asked for a workaround so that the sys does not get locked.But here i m m asking if sys is locked then how do i unlock.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Caffeine to keep the laptop logged on when you are away from the office overnight. You could then set up a scheduled task to run a batch file for a QTP script to kick off at a set time. Caffeine will ensure that no screensavers kick in or auto logs offs occur.

Comment: Caffeine runs in the background and will prevent Windows from logging out due to inactivity. So you wouldn't need to unlock it as it wouldn't be locked. It will simply be idle until the scheduled task kicks off.

Comment: But my req is different.I want the sys to be locked and later when i want to run the script i want to unlock through code

Answer (score 0):

I found a proposed solution that uses [AutoIt and TightVNC](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/71333-solution-to-computer-locked-screen-ctrl-alt-del-scripting/).  I don't think you're going to find a solution directly in VBScript (that would be a major security hole), but VNC programs have long allowed you to send the unlock command.